# adding attributes to a (input) field for next time loading via a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a webpage with a few input fields. What I want to do is, if I have chosen one of the field this time, the web page should focus automatically on the same, on next-time load.

I can imagine that cookies is the way to go. What I don't understand is how should I add an attribute, such as "autofocus" to a specific input field via a cookie.

Any help would be great.
TIA,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

You could store the name (or id) of the input field in the cookie, then in `<head>`, override the function `setFocusOnLoad()` to set the focus on the desired element.  In order to store the most-recent input field in the cookie, you'd probably have to set the value in the cookie every time the user selects a different input field.

Here is an example of how to set the focus on a specific element: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_focus

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea given by @Nathan Wallace, I solved my own question in a different way.

Firstly, I inject a javascript to add the input field in question to a document cookie by

```
$(this).click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).is(":input")){
         event.preventDefault();
         document.location = "this-clicked:"+window.location;

         // this is the function which writes the cookie
         writeCookie(event)
    }
});
```

I could have written the function writeCookie() itself inside the if statement above, but I like keeping different things separate. Otherwise, the writeCookie function is as follows

```
function writeCookie(event) {

   var expirationTime = new Date();
   expirationTime.setTime(expirationTime.getTime() + EXPTIME);
   document.cookie="focusOnMe=" +
                   escape(event.target.id) + 
                   "; expires="+expirationTime.toGMTString();
}
```

That's all with this session. 
Now, every time the page is loaded, I check for if the cookie exists

```
function readElementFromCookie() {

    var allcookies = document.cookie;

    // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
    cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

   // Now take key value pair out of this array
   for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
       name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
       value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
       if (name == "focusOnMe") {
          return value;
       }
   }
}
```

And if this function returns a non-empty value, then I make the webpage focus on the element by

```
 ELEM = readElementFromCookie();
 if (ELEM) {
    javascript: document.getElementById("ELEM").focus();
 }
```

Of course, in the same, I could make the earlier set cookie expire by force to keep the flow only one way.

Nikhil